# How do I unlock a blocked ignition on a Renault Megane 3?

Tags: renault, ignition-switch, megane

I've been doing some repairs and now that everything is in place I can't get it to start. I start classically with the key, and in this case, the key turns only a quarter of the way and it doesn't go any further. At the same time, when the engine was running, the key was turned 180 degrees. So, when you press the clutch and turn the handle, the warning lights come on classically, and when you press the key again, it clicks, but the car does not start.

I already had a similar problem in the past, but the service desk told me it was the spark plugs. Then the battery and electrical circuits were fine, I started the car with an external starter, it drove normally, but it did not start by itself. Of course, I can test the battery again, and go through the fuses and electrical circuits, but I'm wondering if the problem is the anti-theft safety lock, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzaGP_P6ByA). The car, just like last time, locked the trunk, which smells like anti-theft insurance to me.

What I did was disconnect the front fender panels and the left rearview mirror and also disconnect the battery circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I bought a new battery and it started just fine. The problem was probably in the battery, which was weaker on Voltage, but still within the limits. There might be a problem with ampere flow and I suspect that the battery was missing one cell.

Answer (score 0):

(1)If the steering column lock isn't engaged, wheel left in straight forward position, then the mechanical steering wheel lock isn't the problem. If you leave the steering wheel cocked after turning the ign switch off, the column lock may engage as soon as you turn the wheel to prevent the ign switch from turning. In this case, you must turn the wheel away a few degrees from the spring loaded direction then work the ignition switch to feel it unlock as you're relieving mechanical pressure on the lock cylinder. If this isn't a steering lock issue then you're likely to have (2) battery/battery cable and their connections issues. (3) Third consideration may be a worn out clutch safety switch, mounted near the clutch pedal swing arm. The pedal must be pressed fully to engage the safety switch allowing the starting circuit to supply 12v power to the starter solenoid for starting.